# Cambio de configuracion de tipo de archivo en pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Cambie sin querer la configuracion del tipo de archivo en Pycharm y ahora no me ejecuta el codigo y al parecer todos los archivos estan formato de texto y no se como cambiar la configuracion, ya que soy principiante aun [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi es como se ve ahora mi muro en pycharm despues de haber cambiado la configuracion

Comment: ¿Qué cambiaste dónde? ¿Qué opción ejecutaste?

Comment: al parecer cambie por accidente el tipo de archivo con el que trabaja PYCHARM y ahora todos los archivos aparecen en formato texto y no en formato python y no se como revertirlo @CandidMoe